# My HTML email does not fit to iPhone screen, how can I fix it?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, resize

Specifically, the main header is separate from the imagery and footer of the email, pushed too far left for some reason. However, it works perfectly on all other email clients (See SendinBlue campaign builder preview).

Here is the full code I'm using for the address bar at the top:

```html
 <table class="ecxw320" align="center" border="0"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                <tbody>
                  <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                    <td height="50">
                      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                        cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <table align="center" border="0"
                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    
                                    <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"><a
                                        moz-do-not-send="true"
href="http://partofthekult.com/"
                                        target="_blank"
                                        style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"> 
                                        </a></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px;"><a
                                moz-do-not-send="true"
href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tees"
                                target="_blank"
                                style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">TEES
                                 </a></td>
                            <td width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0"
                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                width="2">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px;"><a
                                moz-do-not-send="true"
href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tanks"
                                target="_blank"
                                style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">TANKS</a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0"
                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                width="2">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px;"><a
                                moz-do-not-send="true"
href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/accessories"
                                target="_blank"
                                style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">ACCESSORIES
                                 </a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0"
                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                width="2">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;padding:10px;"><a
                                moz-do-not-send="true"
href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/sale"
                                target="_blank"
                                style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">SALE</a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0"
                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                width="2">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Images of how it renders on my iPhone 6s:
[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OclhX.jpg)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub3ym.png)

Comment: iphone mail support media query, use it to adjust template.

Comment: Which media query to be exact? I've been using this one to no avail: 

<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
        .ecxw320{
            height:auto !important;
            max-width:600px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
</style>

Comment: In my email i use this: `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #content {width:560px!important;}
  #content table {width: 100%!important}
 }`

Comment: Now it seems to be correcting the header, but pushing out other elements of the email further down.